# Upload multiple files with casperjs and each

Tags: casperjs

There is a dynamic image loader I am trying to write a script for. It needs images fed one by one.

I tried to use `each` to add navigation steps but it doesn't work (`images` come from previous ajax call and it is non-empty array):

```
c.start(url)
.then(function fetchDetails(){
  fields = this.evaluate(function evalFetchDetails(){
    var response = __utils__.sendAJAX(fieldsUrl , 'GET', null, false);
    return JSON.parse( response );
  });
    images = [fields.z1, fields.z2, fields.z3, fields.z4, fields.z5, fields.z6, fields.z7, fields.z8];
})
```

I tried this:

```
.each(images, function uploadImage(self, img) {
    console.log("img:" + img); // this won't show
    c.page.uploadFile( '.upload-action [name=u]', img );
    c.waitWhileSelector(".loadingSmall", function(){
      console.log('loaded?'); // neither this
    }, null, 180000);
  })
```

**So is there an elegant way to tackle this?**
because now I'm stuck with this nested-if-callback-poo and my eyes bleed:

```
.then( function uploadPhotos (){
    c.page.uploadFile('.upload-action [name=u]', fields['z1'])
    c.waitWhileSelector(".loadingSmall", function uploadImageAfterWhile(){
          console.log('loaded', fields.z1);
          if (fields.z2)
            c.page.uploadFile('.upload-action [name=u]', fields['z2'])
   ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I should have used `each` within `then`:

```
c.then(function uploadImages(){
    c.each(fields.images, function uploadImage(self, img) {
      c.then(function(){
        c.page.uploadFile( '.upload-action [name=u]', img );
        c.waitWhileSelector(".loadingSmall",
      });
```

otherwise (I suspect) images were not present at the time of running `c.each` - but only after previous steps, so `.then` was needed here.

Comment: Does it work now? If `images` is populated by an AJAX call, then `then` still probably wouldn't cut it. I think you need `waitFor*`, but it is impossible to say without seeing how `images` was populated.

Comment: Ok, it works because the ajax call is synchronous. The problem was that at time of *scheduling* of `each`, the `images` variable was undefined and this undefined was passed into `each`. Because `undefined` is passed by value and not by reference, a later assignment of `images` wouldn't change the `images` that was passed to `each`.